# Problem with home page misaligned on website

Tags: 7, panels, breadcrumbs

The site in question is http://johannabolhoven.co.uk/.

As you can no doubt see, the home page seems to be misaligned from the other pages.
I've got the disable breadcrumbs module installed and I'm wondering if the problem is that the space is still being left for the disabled breadcrumbs, but it could also be something else.

I've tried (to the best of my ability) to disable the breadcrumb div in the template files, but that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: Link to website doesn't work.

Comment: noticed you are using Artisteer to create the Theme.  How do you like it?

Comment: The home page doesn't seem misaligned to me. I must say, my screen has a resolution of 1600x900; maybe that could explain why I don't see any issue.

Comment: There is less space between the main nav and the Johanna img on the home page than in the non-home pages.  See my answer below for the cause/fix.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  You have a custom content pane when you have an image that is inside of a p tag.  That p tag has a margin of 12px on the top and bottom and the image has 10px border on all sides.  Remove that and you should be good to go.

```
<div class="art-sheet-body">
 <div class="art-content-layout">
  <div class="art-content-layout-row">
   <div class="art-layout-cell art-content">
    <div class="art-post">
     <div class="art-post-body">
      <div class="art-post-inner art-article">
       <div class="art-postcontent">
        <div class="region region-content">
         <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
          <div class="panel-2col-stacked clearfix panel-display">
           <div class="center-wrapper">
            <div class="panel-col-first panel-panel">
             <div class="inside">
              <div class="panel-pane pane-custom pane-1">
               <div class="pane-content">
                <p>
                 <img style="width: 200px; height: 78px;" src="/sites/default/files/Signature orange.png" alt="">
                </p>
```

I got this from http://johannabolhoven.co.uk/personal_shopping.

Let me know if there were other issues that you had, but the home page being higher than the other pages was the only thing I could find.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the responses. I find Artisteer good for quick and dirty themes and if you are quite creative with it you can get some good results. Where it falls down is trying to make sense of what's going on behind the scenes when you do want to modify the code. I can't figure out how to fix the problem, even through it's now identified, as far as I can see all the pages are created the same way. In fact most of the other pages were cloned from the home page, which lead me to believe it is something to do with space for the breadcrumb.

Comment: In fact, I decided to try something. I modified the Personal Shopping page to the Home Page and vice versa and it became the Personal Shopping page that was out of line with the others. So my guess it is a result of the space for the breadcrumb.

Comment: Have you tried changing the css files manually?

Comment: Hi Nmillin,Apologies for the delay in responding to this but the client went on holiday so the project got shelved while they were away. I haven't tried changing the css files manually. I wouldn't know where to start. However I have noticed that it isn't just an artisteer themes problem. I changed the default to Bartik and the problem still exists. I think it's definitely a breadcrumb type of thing.#